# CSS styles of a chatter page in iframe don't update

Tags: chatter, css, iframe

I have inserted the chatter page of salesforce in an iframe:

```
<iframe id="showPage" src="{!$Site.Prefix}/_ui/core/chatter/ui/ChatterPage"  style="width:100%; height:600px; margin:0px;" frameBorder="0" onload="changeStylesChatter();"/>
```

The changeStylesChatter() function is used to hide some elements:

```
function changeStylesChatter() {
    var frame = getElementByIdCS("showPage");

    //Hide follow column
    var rightContent = frame.contentDocument.getElementById("rightContent");
    if(typeof rightContent !== 'undefined'){
        rightContent.style.display = 'none';
    }

    //Hide the topics from the comments
    var commentTopics =frame.contentDocument.
        getElementsByClassName("feeditemtopics");
    if(typeof commentTopics !== 'undefined'){
        for (i = 0; i < commentTopics.length; i++) { 
            commentTopics[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
};
```

The changeStylesChatter() function changes the styles of the chatter page correctly with javascript, but I have a little problem. On the first load of the page, watching the 'What I Follow' feed, the styles are correctly applied and the topics are not shown. However, if I change the page to 'To me' feed and go back to the 'What I Follow' feed the topics can be seen in 'What I Follow' feed.

How can I achieve to have the styles applied in all the pages loaded in the iframe?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but you can't detect when the user changes the page in the iframe.
The only way is to apply the styles directly on the pages loaded in the iframe.